# How to fix scheduled tasks after upgrade from ColdFusion 9 to 10

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-10

After upgrading and migrating from ColdFusion 9 to 10, all of our scheduled tasks are gone. In the logs, there are "Advance Scheduling support is not available in this edition of ColdFusion server" errors.  I know this is a known issue that was fixed in the first update.  At this point, ColdFusion 10 is on update 10 (which docs says is cumulative so should include update 1), and documentation says to first install the mandatory update then update 10.  We did this before migrating, however our scheduled tasks still do not appear in the CF admin console.  In other threads on the subject, I've read that we may need to add the "html" extension to the new neo-cron.xml (we have tasks that create static output), but that doesn't seem to be directly correlated to the issue of not seeing our scheduled tasks at all. Any ideas?  We're running CF on Windows Server 2003 (SP2)/IIS 6.

Even if CF doesn't recognize our tasks, is there a way to take our neo-cron.xml from CF 9 and import it into 10 to recreate our tasks?

Comment: Have you tried creating a [ColdFusion Archive](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd3.html) of your scheduled tasks on your CF9 server and then importing that into your CF10 server?

Comment: From what I understand that functionality is only available in the enterprise edition - we're on standard. We made a clone of our server and attempted to install updates separately, i.e. mandatory update, then update 1, then update 9, but the problem persists. We still get an "Advanced scheduling support is not available in this edition of ColdFusion server" error and migration of scheduled tasks fails. The scheduling support issue seems to be the fundamental issue.

Comment: Are you upgrading from CF9 Enterprise to CF10 Standard?

Comment: No, from CF9 Standard to CF10 Standard. Advanced scheduled tasks originally didn't work in CF10 Standard, but that was identified as a bug and was fixed (supposedly) in the first update.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion. All of the issues that I am seeing related to that bug are for _recurring_ tasks. Can you create a recurring task on your new CF10 server? Something you could try - on your cloned CF9 server change all of your recurring scheduled tasks to be non-recurring (choose one-time). Then perform your upgrade and see if it brings the tasks over. If it does then you could change them back to recurring. It's a long shot but might work.

Comment: The thing is that we have a lot of scheduled tasks and are trying to avoid manual intervention. If we were to do that, rather than touch each task twice, we'd probably just recreate them manually in CF10. I'm experimenting with dropping them from the old neo-cron.xml into the new neo-cron.xml file. This seems to have worked for my small test sample of one. I'll test this some more, but likely we'll just bag the upgrade for now. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: It's been awhile, how did the test go?

Answer (score 1):

I believe in CF10, tasks require an `onComplete`.

So  after the tag

```
<struct type='coldfusion.scheduling.ScheduleTagData'>
```

add the line below for each task

```
<var name='oncomplete'><string></string></var>
```