# Migrate CF8 schedule tasks to CF10

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-10

After upgrading and migrating from ColdFusion 8 to 10, all of our scheduled tasks are gone.

Is there a way to use our neo-cron.xml from CF 8 and import it into CF10.

Comment: Did you archive the settings and redeploy them and it didn't work, or what? How did you "migrate"?

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17155482/1636917) for additional discussion on this topic. Although that question was never answered it brings up some other points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try migrating the settings using the CAR file (if you are using Enterprise version). Alternatively, you can copy the neo-cron.xml from CF8 (ColdFusion8/lib) folder to CF10 (ColdFusion10\cfusion\lib) folder. Restart CF service to apply the changes.